# Gfycat video in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-video, gfycat

I'm embedding [gfycat](https://gfycat.com/ru/) video on a page without iframe.
Gfycat stores videos in three different places, depending on it's size: `zippy` for small, `fat` for bigger and `giant` for the largest. I know only video `ID` and don't know where it is stored.
So, I just add sources for each store.
Here's code repeating the inner structure of [iframe embed](https://gfycat.com/ifr/SimilarFlimsyBarasinga):

```
<video preload="none" loop>
    <source src="//zippy.gfycat.com/{{ID}}.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="//fat.gfycat.com/{{ID}}.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="//giant.gfycat.com/{{ID}}.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

After it I call `play` method, here's exemplary JS:

```
video_element.play();
```

For example, [this video](https://gfycat.com/SimilarFlimsyBarasinga) stores at `giant` store. So, first two sources responses with 403 code, but last source is valid and video is playing.
**I understand that this is not really beautiful solution**, but it it works well in Chrome, Firefox and Opera. But not in Safari.
Safari applies first source, it responses 403 and then other two sources doesn't apply automatically, as it happens in other browsers.
So, haw can I solve this problem? Given that I can use only JS, do not know the store and can't use iframe.
Here's [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jfv4mpo7/) to test.

Comment: Ah, Safari, the new Internet Explorer (Yes, this comment again, I know).

Comment: @JeremyThille (╯︵╰)

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice to formulate urls in that fashion as they could change at any time. In fact, it looks like the zippy and fat subdomain urls are not being used by Gfycat anymore.

You should instead use their api to retrieve the data in JSON format and use javascript to update the source urls of the video element.

You may want to check this out: https://github.com/gfycat/gfycat.js